# É possível desestruturar um array em PHP igual ou semelhante a lista em Python?

Tags: php, lista, tupla

Em Python podemos desestruturar uma lista desse jeito:

```python
lista = [ "Maça", "Pera" ]
maca, pera = lista
print(maca, pera)
```

a saída será:

```
Maça Pera
```

Sei que em PHP é possível obter o resultado utilizando a função [`list`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php)

```
$lista = [ "Maça", "Pera" ];
list($maca, $pera) = $lista;
echo "{$maca} {$pera}";
```

mas gostaria de saber se é possível obter o resultado utilizando a mesma notação ou parecida com do Python?

Comment: Acho que o mais próximo é usar o `list`, mas pode usar `[$maca, $pera] = $lista`, tem o mesmo comportamento do `list($maca, $pera) = $lista`, mas omite o `list`.

Comment: @Inkeliz estou utilizando a versão *7.0.1* e estou tendo o erro: `<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in <b>[...][...]</b>`

Comment: [Isso é possível no PHP 7.1+.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bb2117776d1b0f1ec218cc7197dac526766ed29)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não, não é possível, PHP não tem o conceito de tuplas, por isso é impossível da mesma forma. Mas isto não é importante, o que importa é conseguir o que precisa. E convenhamos, é quase a mesma coisa. Conforme o inkeliz comentou é possível melhorar um pouco usando a notação de lista direta:

```
$lista = ["Maça", "Pera"];
[$maca, $pera] = $lista;
echo "{$maca} {$pera}";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/838bqF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lgybrdha-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ListDeconstruction.php).

PHP tem a ideia que o *array* resolve tudo, então faz sentido ser assim e não precisar de novas estruturas. Claro PHP anda traindo sua raiz e criando outras formas, então pode ser que um dia tenha tupla.

Answer (score -4):

Você pode usar lista para isso!

```
list($var1, $var2) =  ["Valor de var1", "Valor de var2"];
```