# Como declarar variaveis PHP a partir das chaves de um array

Tags: php

Existe alguma forma de declarar as variáveis no php da mesma forma que fazemos no Javascript?

Gostaria de fazer isso:

```
const { variavel1, variavel2, variavel3 } = array
```

Para simplificar isso:

```
$variavel1 = $array['variavel1'];
$variavel2 = $array['variavel2'];
$variavel3 = $array['variavel3'];
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486846/69296

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [É possível desestruturar um array em PHP igual ou semelhante a lista em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/341583/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-desestruturar-um-array-em-php-igual-ou-semelhante-a-lista-em-python)

Answer (score 8):

### Recurso nativo: o `list`

Este recurso existe desde o PHP 4, é o `list()`. É simples assim:

```
list($variavel1, $variavel2, $variavel3) = $array;
```

Nos PHPs mais novos aceita esta sintaxe simplificada, mas é o mesmo *construct*:

```
[$variavel1, $variavel2, $variavel] = $array;
```

Desde o PHP 7.1 você pode escolher os ítens com índices (cuidado, começa de 0):

```
list(1 => $variavel2, 2 => $variavel3) = $array;
[1 => $variavel2, 2 => $variavel3] = $array;
```

Ou ainda, omitir variáveis que não precisa:

```
list( , $variavel2, $variavel3 ) = $array;
```

### Exemplo:

```
$array = [
    'UM',
    'DOIS',
    'TRES'
];
 
list($variavel1, $variavel2, $variavel3) = $array;
 
echo "Var 1: $variavel1\n";
echo "Var 2: $variavel2\n";
echo "Var 3: $variavel3\n";
```

Resultado:

```
Var 1: UM
Var 2: DOIS
Var 3: TRES
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/uwu1nC)**

Manual:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer dessa forma para arrays associativos:

```
$array = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
];
['c' => $c, 'a' => $a] = $array;
```

Ou no caso de uma lista:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
[$a, $b, $c] = $array;
```

Utilizando seu exemplo nós teriamos algo assim:

```
['variavel1' => $variavel1, 'variavel2' => $variavel2, 'variavel3' => $variavel3] = $array
```

**OBS: O array destructuring esá disponível a partir da versão 7.1 do PHP**

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

```
<?php

$arr = array('primeiro' =>  '1',
             'segundo'  =>  '2',
             'terceiro' =>  '3');

extract($arr);

echo $primeiro;

/* Imprimirá -> 1 */
```

Comment: Não fui eu que dei -1 mas o problema do `extract` é que o programador não tem controlo das variáveis criadas, ao passo nas outras respostas com destructuring e list isso não acontece. Ainda ressaltando o que a doc diz: `Warning Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).`